# Adding dataset files on the google colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to upload cifar data-set to google colabratory. i consists of

> 'batches.meta','data_batch_1','data_batch_2','data_batch_3','data_batch_4','data_batch_5','test_batch'

I would like to add upload multiple files and add them to the same place to act on them

Answer (score 20):

you could upload somewhere, after that you can download from code cell notebooks and use this shell command: *wget*

for ex:

```
!wget http://your_domain/your_file.zip
```

note: we use '!' for running shell command in a notebook.

Comment: in what path does it save it locally?

Comment: hi @0x90 you can use `!ls`