# Uploading file to a specific directory on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use Google Collaboratory with a specific library. I've installed the library but it appears that there is one file which is missing.

I have the file, is there any way that I can upload it to the required directory?

The error I get is:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/climt/_data/ozone_profile.npy
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is the library you are attempting to install?

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465062/adding-dataset-files-on-the-google-colaboratory/49573122#49573122