# Is there some way to directly upload dataset from some website to colaboratory?

Tags: dataset, google-colaboratory

For example this is a Cat and Dog Dataset on microsoft's website and I want to use this data for my model. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=54765

Comment: Please [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also you can call shell commands from jupyter (or colaboratory) like `wget` with `!` at the start

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding dataset files on the google colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465062/adding-dataset-files-on-the-google-colaboratory)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wget` shell command with the direct link

```
!wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/E/1/3E1C3F21-ECDB-4869-8368-6DEBA77B919F/kagglecatsanddogs_3367a.zip
```

Comment: How did you get this link?and how can we use the downloaded data? Like how to store them in variables and etc. for further use.

Comment: There is `'click here to download manually'` link. The answer to the second question depends on your data format. Normally people use either `numpy` or `pandas` to load data.